# Custom Implementation of InputStream with LinkedBlockingQueue hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, stream

I tried implementing an InputStream that I can pass chunks of strings to it.
Technically, it should work because all I needed to do is block the InputStream#read() method and that's about it. Or so I thought so...
Here is my custom implementation of the StringInputStream:

```
public class StringInputStream extends InputStream {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void supplyData(String s) {
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            buffer.add((int) ch);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        try {
            return buffer.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And here is my code to test it:

```
public class StreamsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("eu ma duc la scoala\n sa ma distrez\nsi imi place la MAXIM!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(is);
        AtomicReference<StringInputStream> inputStream = new AtomicReference<>(new StringInputStream());
        Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream.get());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println("2. " + scanner.nextLine());
            }
        });
        th.start();

        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner1.nextLine();
            inputStream.get().supplyData(line + "\n");
            System.out.println("1. " + line);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nwaiting 3 seconds to exit from MAIN thread");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        //th.interrupt();
        System.out.println("exited MAIN thread");
    }
}
```

In my example, I am reading from the first inputstream, I supply the lines to my custom implementation and then I read from my custom implementation in another thread.

Now the strange thing:
I don't see any output UNLESS I decomment the th.interrupt() line and this happens ONLY the sleeping from the main thread ( which doesn't makes sense because I am reading from my StringInputStream in another thread ).

Can you help me spot the problem please?

Kind regards,

Comment: FYI: An `InputStream` is for reading _bytes_.  A `Reader` is for reading _characters_ or Strings.  You should _really really_ not mix up the two.

Comment: I’ll bet the `Scanner` uses buffered I/O and the entire contents you push is smaller than this buffer size. So it hangs waiting for more incoming data when you are not pushing anything anymore. Since you return `-1`, aka end-of-file, on interruption, it ends the waiting. The correct solution would be to push some sort of end-of-file marker to the stream which the consuming thread can read.

Answer (score 1):

I actually became curious of this myself so I started looking this up

When I tried

```
Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("Before scanner initialization");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream.get());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("2. " + scanner.nextLine());
    }
});
th.start();
```

The print before the scanner initialization printed, which means that the initialization of the new scanner is blocking the thread.

Now I haven't actually ever tried inheriting from the InputStream class, but when I tried doing this on the main thread, the initialization didn't block.

---

Actually the code blocks here

```
AtomicReference<StringInputStream> inputStream = new AtomicReference<>(new StringInputStream());
System.out.println("before");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream.get());
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { // Code is blocking here
    System.out.println("2. " + scanner.nextLine());
}
System.out.println("after");
```

So before is printed whereas after is not.

---

Figured it out

I'm not sure of your exact requirements but if you want to use Scanner with your InputStream, you should be overrriding

```
read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

In addition to `read()` since you are extending an interface. The read however won't get called from Scanner. You can try this class to see if it works.

```
class StringInputStream extends InputStream {

    byte[] bytes;
    int index = 0;

    public StringInputStream(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public int read() {
        return bytes[index];
    }


    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        if(index == bytes.length)
            return 0;
        b[0] = bytes[index++];
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The class will return false from `scanner.hasNextLine()` if you return 0 bytes from `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`. Guess you learn something new each day.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Found where the code is blocking--even when running on the main thread, are you sure your implementation of StringInputStream?

Comment: I am supposed to only implement the read method. Also I tried implementing the others read methods and make all methods synchronized but like this, it sometimes work, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: But I need to fetch chunks of Strings continuously. Also, doesn't the read method must block if we have no data, rather than return 0 ?

Comment: If you need to fetch chunks of Strings continuously, you should update the constructor and internal variable of the StringInputStream class to fit your needs. When you return 0, `scanner.hasNextLine()` returns false and you should terminate. Did you try running the above code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107649/discussion-between-user3030447-and-jrhee17).